# Creating a new Thread in each iteration of foreach loop

Tags: c#, multithreading

I detect faces in image files inside a folder using Emgu CV. I'm using a `foreach` loop for this. However, the form does not respond until the whole process is finished.

I use threads to avoid this. However, the thread is not working as I expected. The loop ends before the rendering of the images is finished.

```
foreach (var item in files)
{
  Img = Image.FromFile(item);
  string savefile = Path.Combine(path, "eo", dirname, Path.GetFileName(file));
  Thread th = new Thread(() => ModernUI.FaceDetect.imageprocessmulti(Img, savefile, savepath));
  th.Start();
}
```

Even if I do it this way, it works like it was before using threads.

```
th.Start();
th.Join();
```

Comment: If you're using Winforms, consider a BackgroundWorker control.

Comment: What is the type of your project? Win Forms?

Comment: You also need to dispose of your images (`Image.FromFile(item)`) after you've used them.

Comment: Can you be more specific? "However, the thread is not working as I expected. " what is the end result?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's one way to approach it using `async/await`, for example, with a button click event:

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => {
            foreach (var item in files)
            {
                Img = Image.FromFile(item);
                string savefile = Path.Combine(path, "eo", dirname, Path.GetFileName(file));
                ModernUI.FaceDetect.imageprocessmulti(Img, savefile, savepath);                    
            }
        });
        
        // ...more code here to run after all images have been processed...
        MessageBox.Show("Done!");
    }
```

Here's an alternate version to show progress, not sure what you tried:

```
    private async void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Visible = true;
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        int total = files.Length;

        await Task.Run(() => {
            foreach (var item in files)
            {
                Img = Image.FromFile(item);
                string savefile = Path.Combine(path, "eo", dirname, Path.GetFileName(file));
                ModernUI.FaceDetect.imageprocessmulti(Img, savefile, savepath);

                counter++;
                int p = (int)((double)counter / total * 100);
                progressBar1.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {
                    progressBar1.Value = p;
                });
            }
        });

        // ...more code here to run after all images have been processed...
        progressBar1.Visible = false;
        MessageBox.Show("Done!");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked this way. However, when I added the progressbar to the system, it didn't work. So I changed the await task to include only the method.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing is to change from `Thread` to `Task` (and correctly dispose of your image) like this:

```
foreach (var item in files)
{
    using (Image img = Image.FromFile(item))
    {
        string savefile = Path.Combine(path, "eo", dirname, Path.GetFileName(file));
        await Task.Run(() => ModernUI.FaceDetect.imageprocessmulti(img, savefile, savepath));
    }
}
```

That **MUST** be done in a `async Task` method (or `async void` event handler) to allow the use of the `await` keyword.

This approach will run each `imageprocessmulti` one after the other without blocking the UI.

If you want to run all of the `imageprocessmulti` in parallel, then you're best off making a list of tasks and awaiting them all at once. Like this:

```
List<Task> tasks =
(
    from item in files
    let savefile = Path.Combine(path, "eo", dirname, Path.GetFileName(file))
    select Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (Image img = Image.FromFile(item))
        {
            ModernUI.FaceDetect.imageprocessmulti(img, savefile, savepath);
        }
    })
).ToList();

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

My preferred approach is to use Microsoft's Reactive Framework - NuGet `System.Reactive` - and then do this:

```
IObservable<Unit> query =
    from item in files.ToObservable(Scheduler.Default)
    let savefile = Path.Combine(path, "eo", dirname, Path.GetFileName(file))
    from unit in Observable.Using(
        () => Image.FromFile(item),
        img => Observable.Start(() => ModernUI.FaceDetect.imageprocessmulti(img, savefile, savepath)))
    select unit;

await query.ToArray();
```

All of these approaches should work for you.